# Use query to sum two rows and group by another

Tags: google-sheets

Current formula: `=QUERY(QUERY(A:B, "SELECT A, SUM(B) WHERE A <> '' GROUP BY A"),"WHERE Col2 >0")`

Data set:

[image]

Query output:

[image]

I want to add F & G to the QUERY to do the same thing. Essentially summing B & G and making sure they correspond to the name in F. So CD's amount would be "500".

[image]

EDIT: Also columns I & J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First stack both columns vertically and then use `QUERY()` function to calculate. Try-

```
=QUERY(VSTACK(A2:B,F2:G),"select Col1, sum(Col2) 
where Col1 is not null 
group by Col1
label Col1 'Asset', sum(Col2) 'Sum of Amount'")
```

[image]

Comment: You can stack more columns if you need.